# Function to schedule file deletion after x-hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, time, directory

I found the below function [here](https://koderplace.com/code-samples/295/delete-files-older-than-n-days-in-a-directory-using-python) and edited it a little to delete my files after 2 hours (checks every 1 minute), I want to use it to clean my server's download directory (Linux) after a certain time.
The strange thing is that it won't delete the manually created files, but as I download the videos using `youtube-dl`, it immediately deletes them!
I realized that the modified time of these files isn't correct;
 I downloaded them yesterday (`3/2/2022 20:45`), but the modified time in my Windows explorer was (`1/17/2022 17:51`).
As I don't know how to work with `st_mtime` & `st_ctime` to achieve the same result on both Windows and Linux systems, please help me if this function has issues for this purpose, or if you know a better way...
I need a simple elegant function...

**Function**

```py
import os, time

def RemoveFiles(dir_path, hours):
'''
    dir_path: Path where the files are stored (⚠ Change it to your path, e.g. './DLDir'). 
    hours: Delete files older than n hours (e.g. 12).
'''

    while True:
        # Creates a list containing the name of all files in the directory.
        all_files = os.listdir(dir_path)
        # Stores the seconds passed since the epoch (For Unix system, January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 at UTC is epoch [the point where time begins]).
        now = time.time()
        n_hours = hours * 3600
        for f in all_files:
            # Joins the base path with the file name.
            file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, f)
            # If the thing in the path is a file and not a directory.
            # Dir = F, not F = T, continue.
            if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
                continue
            # stat() returns a stat_result object.
            # st_mtime is the time of last modification.
            if os.stat(file_path).st_mtime < now - n_hours:
                os.remove(file_path)
                print(f"♻♻♻ Deleted: ♻♻♻ {f}")
        
        sys_starttime_forsleep = time.time()
        # Specify the seconds you want to wait (first argument).
        time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - sys_starttime_forsleep) % 60.0))
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387132/youtube-dl-and-no-mtime-what-does-it-mean (use --no-mtime to stop youtube-dl from changing the mtime)

Comment: @barrycarter thank you so much! it's what i wanted.